# 2 unrelated divs to have the same height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 different divs with different parents and I would like to make them the height of the tallest one.

I managed that with the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = Math.max($("#left").height(), $("#right").height());
    $("#left").height(height);
    $("#right").height(height);
});
</script>
```

the html:

```
<div class="contact-information">
   <div class="centered" id="right">
       <h3>INFORMATII</h3>
       <p>Strada</p>
       <div class="social-icons-wrapper">
          ....                  
       </div><!-- social-icons-wrapper -->
   </div><!-- centered -->
</div><!-- contact-information -->

<div class="contact-box">
    <div class="width-for-centering" id="left">
         <div class="contact-title">
             <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE!</h3>
             <p>Completeaza</p>
         </div><!-- contact-title -->

         <div class="tocenter" data-aos="zoom-out">
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="63" title="formular"]'); ?>
         </div><!-- tocenter -->
    </div><!-- width-for-centering -->
</div><!-- contact-box -->
```

And the css

```
#right{
width:400px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#left{
width:600px;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
padding-bottom: 0;
position: relative;
top:50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

This works, both divs now have the same height, my problem is that they are taller than they should be. Left's children only add up to about 600px in height, but left has 737px in height now.

I found that the problem could be the script above because when I delete it, left does take the height of it's children.

Comment: Add your HTML also

Comment: Can you add your HTML code?

Comment: Add your html markup as well.

Comment: I also added the html. I forgot about it. http://lencos.ro/7greendays/ bottom part with the contact form

Comment: What browsers are you targetting - are they recent enough [for flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)?

Comment: The latest browsers, not at all interested in earlier versions.

Comment: `Left's children only add up to about 600px in height, but left has 737px in height now.` doesn't relate to your code!!!

Comment: That's what I am seeing in my browsers - both firefox and chrome. I added a link to the site in my previous comment. Maybe the visuals will explain better.

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is with your CSS. Specifically with the position:absolute; and transform.

Look at this fiddle where I used your code without CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/g0utu4bz/

```
var height = Math.max($("#left").height(), $("#right").height());
$("#left").height(height);
$("#right").height(height);
```

Comment: there is no position absolute. just relative. and I removed the transform, i even removed all css line apart from width and the problem is still there. I might have to rethink the script.

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? it works there. Both containers have the height of the tallest one.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited the content using flex-box and media queries, in order to match the request... and i've added some css to be a litte more mobile-friendly (but is only a little optimization, your layout need some more work ;) )

I hope that this will be helpful!

P.s. expand the snipped ("run code" -> "full page") to see correcty how media queries works, otherwise you'll see only 1 column!

```css
.left-right-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  /* this rules will be used only on devices with large screen, to make the layout a little bit more responsive */
  .left-right-container {
    flex-direction: row;
   }
   .left-right-container .left {
      width: 600px;
    }
    .left-right-container .right {
      width: 400px;
    }
    .left-right-container .last {
      min-height: 50px; /* as many as you need to show socials */
    }
}
.left-right-container .left, .left-right-container .right {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.left-right-container .left {
  background: green;
}
.left-right-container .right {
  background: red;
}
.left-right-container .left > *, .left-right-container .right > * {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.left-right-container .left > .take-all, .left-right-container .right > .take-all {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-right-container">
<div class="contact-information">
   <div class="centered right">
       <h3>INFORMATII</h3>
       <p>Strada</p>
       <div class="social-icons-wrapper take-all">
          1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6
       </div>
       <div class="last">other content</div>
   </div><!-- centered -->
</div><!-- contact-information -->

<div class="contact-box">
    <div class="width-for-centering left">
         <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE!</h3>
         <p>Completeaza</p>
         <div class="tocenter take-all" data-aos="zoom-out">
            1<br>2<br>3
         </div>
         <div class="last">other content</div>
    </div><!-- width-for-centering -->
</div><!-- contact-box -->
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is I need content height because of the design requested by my customer.

Comment: I don't understand, you need to know the content height? or the content must have a specific height? or the content can't be taller than a certain height? or what? can you please explain? :)

Comment: Sorry, i will explain: both left and right have several divs inside them, some of which need to be on the same horizontal line. So a div from left needs to be on the same line as a div from right. I figured that the only way I can achieve this is if both left and right have the same height and I use position absolute for the children.

Comment: To even better explain, if you check http://lencos.ro/7greendays/ the contact section at the bottom of the page, the social icons on the right need to be on the same line as the submit button on the left.

Comment: I see... edited the answer! by the way, I think that this is a bad approach to the problem, basically because your page is really heavy (13mb!) and is not responsive (a must now a day!) I suggest you to select a particular framework (bootstrap for instance) as a base using columns systems and similar to have a fully responsive page (there are a lot of well-made base template to extends with element similar to your page)... obviously this is only a suggestion for future improvements :)

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy with flexbox, you could do something like this:

```css
.wrapper {
 display: flex;
}

#right{
  width:400px;
  background-color: red;
}

#left{
  width:600px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="contact-information" id="right">
    <div class="centered">
       <h3>INFORMATII</h3>
       <p>Strada</p>
       <div class="social-icons-wrapper">
          ....                  
       </div><!-- social-icons-wrapper -->
     </div><!-- centered -->
  </div><!-- contact-information -->

  <div class="contact-box" id="left">
    <div class="width-for-centering">
         <div class="contact-title">
             <h3>CONTACTEAZA-NE!</h3>
             <p>Completeaza</p>
         </div><!-- contact-title -->
         <div class="tocenter" data-aos="zoom-out">
         </div><!-- tocenter -->
    </div><!-- width-for-centering -->
  </div><!-- contact-box -->
  
</div>
```

Comment: I know it is. The problem is both left and right have separate containers.

Comment: Okay, well have you tried with `outerHeight()` to obtain the height ?

Comment: I gave a variable the value of whichever was taller between left and right and gave both left and right that value for height. This works, both divs have the same height, the problem is they are taller than they should be.